# Error while running HQL From PermitApproval

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql

The error is encountered only while running HQL :

From PermitApproval

i.e from hibernate.xml file in netbeans. Running query in postgres (i.e select * from permitapproval) no such error appears.
Also selecting individual column from table in HQL no error appears

e.g
 
select permitno From PermitApproval
select permitrequest from PermitApproval (permitrequest is another object)

Hibernate Model of PermitApproval below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permitapproval", schema = "excise2")
public class PermitApproval implements Serializable {


 private Permitrequest permitrequest;
 private Transactions transaction;
 private Date validfrom;
 private Date validto;
 private String referencepermitno;
 private Integer currentmonth;
 private Integer currentyear;
 private Modules module;
 private String  officeabbreviation;
 private String finyear;
 private Integer slno;
 private String warehouseabbr;
 private String permitno;
 private Userlogin user;
 private Timestamp entrydate;
 private Date referencedate;
 private ExportRoutes routes;
 private StatesExcise statesexcise;





 public PermitApproval(){

 }

public PermitApproval(modelform.PermitApprovalForm permitapproval) {

    if (permitapproval.getPermitrequest() == null) {
        this.permitrequest = new Permitrequest();
    } else {
        this.permitrequest = new Permitrequest(permitapproval.getPermitrequest());
    }

    if (permitapproval.getTransaction()== null) {
        this.transaction = new Transactions();
    } else {
        this.transaction = new Transactions(permitapproval.getTransaction());
    }

    if (permitapproval.getModule() == null) {
        this.module = new Modules();
    } else {
        this.module = new Modules(permitapproval.getModule());
    }


    if (permitapproval.getUser() == null) {
        this.user = new Userlogin();
    } else {
        this.user = new Userlogin(permitapproval.getUser());
    }

     if (permitapproval.getRoutes()== null) {
        this.routes = new ExportRoutes();
    } else {
        this.routes = new ExportRoutes(permitapproval.getRoutes());
    }

    if (permitapproval.getStatesexcise()== null) {
        this.statesexcise = new StatesExcise();
    } else {
        this.statesexcise = new StatesExcise(permitapproval.getStatesexcise());
    }

    this.currentmonth=permitapproval.getCurrentmonth();
    this.currentyear=permitapproval.getCurrentyear();
    this.slno=permitapproval.getSlno();
    this.finyear=permitapproval.getFinyear();
    this.permitno=permitapproval.getPermitno();
    this.referencepermitno=permitapproval.getReferencepermitno();
    this.warehouseabbr=permitapproval.getWarehouseabbr();
    this.officeabbreviation=permitapproval.getOfficeabbreviation();
    this.valid_from=permitapproval.getValid_from();
    this.valid_to=permitapproval.getValid_to();
    this.entry_date=permitapproval.getEntry_date();
    this.reference_date=permitapproval.getReference_date();

}


@Id
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="applicationcode", referencedColumnName ="applicationcode" ,nullable=false) 
public Permitrequest getPermitrequest() {
    return permitrequest;
}


public void setPermitrequest(Permitrequest permitrequest) {
    this.permitrequest = permitrequest;
}



@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="transactioncode", nullable=false) 
public Transactions getTransaction() {
    return transaction;
}

public void setTransaction(Transactions transaction) {
    this.transaction = transaction;
}

@Column(name = "validfrom", nullable = false)
public Date getValidfrom() {
    return validfrom;
}

public void setValidfrom(Date validfrom) {
    this.validfrom = validfrom;
}

@Column(name = "validto", nullable = false)
public Date getValidto() {
    return validto;
}

public void setValidto(Date validto) {
    this.validto = validto;
}

@Column(name = "referencepermitno", nullable = false)
public String getReferencepermitno() {
    return referencepermitno;
}

public void setReferencepermitno(String referencepermitno) {
    this.referencepermitno = referencepermitno;
}

@Column(name = "currentmonth", nullable = false)
public Integer getCurrentmonth() {
    return currentmonth;
}

public void setCurrentmonth(Integer currentmonth) {
    this.currentmonth = currentmonth;
}

@Column(name = "currentyear", nullable = false)
public Integer getCurrentyear() {
    return currentyear;
}

public void setCurrentyear(Integer currentyear) {
    this.currentyear = currentyear;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="modulecode", nullable=false) 
public Modules getModule() {
    return module;
}

public void setModule(Modules module) {
    this.module = module;
}


@Column(name = "finyear", nullable = false)
public String getFinyear() {
    return finyear;
}

public void setFinyear(String finyear) {
    this.finyear = finyear;
}

@Column(name = "slno", nullable = false)
public Integer getSlno() {
    return slno;
}

public void setSlno(Integer slno) {
    this.slno = slno;
}

@Column(name = "warehouseabbr", nullable = false)
public String getWarehouseabbr() {
    return warehouseabbr;
}

public void setWarehouseabbr(String warehouseabbr) {
    this.warehouseabbr = warehouseabbr;
}


@Column(name = "permitno", nullable = false)
public String getPermitno() {
    return permitno;
}

public void setPermitno(String permitno) {
    this.permitno = permitno;
}


@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="usercode", nullable=false)
public Userlogin getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Userlogin user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Column(name = "entrydate", nullable = false)
public Timestamp getEntrydate() {
    return entrydate;
}

public void setEntrydate(Timestamp entrydate) {
    this.entrydate = entrydate;
}

@Column(name = "officeabbreviation", nullable = false,length=4)
public String getOfficeabbreviation() {
    return officeabbreviation;
}

public void setOfficeabbreviation(String officeabbreviation) {
    this.officeabbreviation = officeabbreviation;
}

@Column(name = "referencedate", nullable = true)
public Date getReferencedate() {
    return referencedate;
}

public void setReferencedate(Date referencedate) {
    this.referencedate = referencedate;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="routecode", nullable=true)
public ExportRoutes getRoutes() {
    return routes;
}

public void setRoutes(ExportRoutes routes) {
    this.routes = routes;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="statesexcisecode", nullable=true)
public StatesExcise getStatesexcise() {
    return statesexcise;
}

public void setStatesexcise(StatesExcise statesexcise) {
    this.statesexcise = statesexcise;
}










private String valid_from;
private String valid_to;
private String entry_date;
private String reference_date;

@Transient
public String getValid_from() {
    return valid_from;
}

public void setValid_from(String valid_from) {
    this.valid_from = valid_from;
}

@Transient
public String getValid_to() {
    return valid_to;
}


public void setValid_to(String valid_to) {
    this.valid_to = valid_to;
}

@Transient
public String getEntry_date() {
    return entry_date;
}

public void setEntry_date(String entry_date) {
    this.entry_date = entry_date;
}

@Transient
public String getReference_date() {
    return reference_date;
}

public void setReference_date(String reference_date) {
    this.reference_date = reference_date;
  }
}
```

NOTE:Running HQL for all the inner table that are mapped inside PermitApproval are working perfectly
i.e From Modules,From permitrequest,From transactions etc

Error is as below :

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4120)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:502)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:467)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:212)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:258)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:150)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1066)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:985)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:673)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:489)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1114)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2551)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2537)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2367)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:229)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1260)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = smallint
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1592)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1327)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:192)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:451)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:350)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
... 32 more
```

I have recheck alot of times each column and their datatype, cannot figure where the cause for this :

**operator does not exist: character varying = smallint**

Use the following : 
Hibernate 4
Postgres 9.5